# Bacula: Stalled disk backup job doesn't resume when disk is remounted

Tags: backup, bacula

I'm using Bacula to backup to a disk file. The thing is, I'm backing up to an external USB disk and I want the backup to be robust to accidental unmounts of the external disk. Ideally, I would like to have the backup job stall if the disk isn't mounted (so it doesn't swamp the server's HDD) but resume when the disk is remounted.

I have accomplished the first objective by setting the backup directory to a specific directory on the external disk so that when the disk is unmounted, Bacula can't find it and the backup job gets stalled. When I remount the disk, however, the job fails to resume.

My current device definition in `bacula-sd.conf`:

```
Device{
  Name=Backups
  Media Type=File
  Archive Device = /mnt/backup/backups/ #Disk mounted on /mnt/backup
  Label Media = Yes;
  Random Access = Yes;
  Removable Media = No; # Otherwise, Bacula expects the backup volumes to already exist on disk
  Requires Mount = No; #Automounted via udev
  Always Open = No;
}
```

Is there a better way to ensure that the backup jobs will automatically resume when `/mnt/backup` is remounted?

---

**Update**

When I cancel the stalled backup job, the queued ones resume normally.

Comment: I think this should work: when udev mounts the disk, pass the mount command to bconsole (`echo whatever | bconsole`).  Plus, you can raise job concurrency on SD to avoid queue stalls.

Comment: @sendmoreinfo Do you mean pass the mount command from within the `udev` rule or manually? I'm hoping to do this with zero intervention.

Comment: within udev rule, yes.